# Blackberry Browsable Error

Tags: android, blackberry, android-intent, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

I am having an issue when I port a application over to blackberry from android.  The app is a webapp and it works on the androids just fine, but when I port it and deploy it on the playbook I am getting an error that says

Action not supported

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.View cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=file:///android_asset/process.html (has extras)}
```

Comment: may be add a datatype in your intent ?

Answer (score 0):

Intent.ACTION_VIEW is not working on bb10

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with a webView inside the app, but setting the webViewClient when I create the webView solved it:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Good luck :)